# Hilbert's Original Proof of the Nullstellensatz

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, math-history

Does anyone have a link to Hilbert's Original Proof of the Nullstellensatz, or know a book where it's printed? I'd be interested to see what it was like. I only really know the Noether normalisation and Zariski proofs. While these are both good, it would be nice to have it 'from the horse's mouth'!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wikipedia hints that it's Hilbert, David (1890), "Ueber die Theorie der algebraischen Formen", Mathematische Annalen 36 (4): 473–534, doi:10.1007/BF01208503,  but I haven't found it after a quick look at the paper (and I don't know German).

Comment: It's probably in Hilbert's collected works: [Gesammelte Abhandlungen](http://www-gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/cgi-bin/digbib.cgi?PPN237833719), volume 2 on Algebra.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Eisenbud, Hilbert's Nullstellensatz can be found in:

- Hilbert, D. (1893). [Über die vollen Invariantensysteme](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01444162). Math. Ann. 42, pp. 313–373. Also freely [available](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002254263) on the GDZ.

The statement of the theorem appears at the bottom of [p. 320](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002254263&PHYSID=phys337), if I'm not mistaken. (I don't read German, however!)

Comment: I am able to read German and I can confirm your finding. Very good reference, thank you!

Comment: An anonymous user [suggested an edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10503) that was rejected just before I could accept it, so I took the liberty of incorporating it because I found it useful, as not everyone has access to the Springer Link articles.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks very much!

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/355838/101848) is an English translation.