# Strong Nullstellensatz without the Rabinowitsch trick

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

All the textbooks I've seen prove the Strong Nullstellensatz from the Weak Nullstellensatz using the Rabinowitsch trick.

How did they prove the Strong Nullstellensatz before the Rabinowitsch trick was invented?

Comment: I guess you mean Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. I tried to find his original proof but could not find it. Don't know how he called the theorem... But I found this: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01187946?LI=true#page-1 I did not read it in full because I dont have free access (or at least not from home). But sounds as it takes another path and mentions a proof by Brauer which is it first reference which seems noy to use the Rabinowitsch trick, too. I hope this might help.

Comment: Here a link to the paper by Brauer: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183512373

Comment: Hilbert's original proof is linked to in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/185275/116766).